# Is LCS $\Omega(n^2)$?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

> Given two sequences of numbers, where each has $n$ elements, find the longest common subsequence

Doesn't LCS have a proof it's $\Omega(n^2)$ in the style of the proof that unsorted search is $\Omega(n)$ ?

I have read some papers, which I didn't understand, saying that it can't be $O(n^{2-\epsilon})$ ,assuming the exponential time hypothesis, but I think that version of LCS was with elements being letters of the alphabet.

This [paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/321921.321922) proves that for comparison-based algorithms (equal-unequal), it is $\Omega(n^2)$.

Could it be that there is an algorithm not based on comparisons that solves it faster? I have this question for sorting as well because we assume in the proof that it's $\Omega(n\log{n})$, that the algorithm is comparison based.

Comment: What does least common subsequence mean?

Comment: Doesn't LCS conventionally refer to *longest* common subsequence instead? If "L" means least, it makes little sense to me.

Comment: The least common subsequence is the empty set $\emptyset$. However, using dynamic programming on the recurrence relation describing the cost of the longest common subsequence, or commonly LCS, one gets $T(n) = \Theta(mn)$ with $m,n$ the lengths of the individual subsequences. Whether the elements of the different sets are letters or numbers it makes no difference.

Comment: Note that the longest common subsequence problem has $mn$ subproblems or more simply $n^2$ assuming the two subsequences have the same number of elements.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the longest, not least.

Comment: Hi prcssngnr. I am aware of the dynamic programming algorithm. I just ask if it is impossible to solve in less time than $\Omega(n^2)$.

Comment: Well there are $mn$ comparisons which need to be made to solve the problem. Unless you can do multiple comparisons simultaneously I don't think you can do better than $\Omega(n^2)$, but I don't know maybe there is some clever way I don't see :).

Comment: Here is a [paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.4.6927&rep=rep1&type=pdf) discussing the time complexity of the LCS problem.

Comment: The [paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.4.6927&rep=rep1&type=pdf) refers to this [paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/321921.321922).

Comment: "When algorithms are
over arbitrary alphabets, use ‘‘equal—unequal’’ comparisons, and are characterized in terms of the size of their
input, it has been shown that Ω(N2 ) time is necessary [1]. A ‘‘Four Russians’’ approach leads to slightly better
O(N2 lglgN/lgN) and O(N2 /lgN) time algorithms for arbitrary and finite alphabets respectively [13]. The
existence of faster algorithms using other comparison formats is still open. Indeed, for algorithms that use ‘‘less
than—equal—greater than’’ comparisons, Ω(NlgN) time is the best lower bound known [9]"

Comment: I read (13) and I find only about the finite alphabet case which they solve in $O(n^2 /log{n})$, using "Four Russians" method which apparently only works for the finite case ( wikipedia says it's for "algorithms involving matrices in which each cell may take on only a bounded number of possible values"). I can't find where they solve arbitary alphabet case in $O(N^2 \frac{\log{\log{n}}}{\log{n}}  )$ in this article. Nonetheless it still suprises me, about the finite alphabet case, It is interesting.